# How to connect to postgresql instance in with Docker Toolbox with pgadmin4 client

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

i'm new to Docker, and i'm running it with Docker Toolbox cause i have win 10 family.
I have a training project where there is a database to put up with docker-compose.
Here is the docker-compose.yml (it's given to me, but i can modify it).

```
 version: '2'
services:
  myerp.db:
    image: postgres:9.4
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:9032:5432"
    volumes:
#      - "./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
       - "./init/db/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=db_myerp
      - POSTGRES_USER=usr_myerp
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myerp
```

When i run that through Docker with docker-compose up it seems ok, 
but i'm unable to connect to it through a server in pgadmin4
I'm not sure of the connexion setup i'm suppose to put because of Docker ToolBox, where in general to access the running instance you don't use 127.0.0.1 but 192.168.99.100 by defaut.
Anyway, if i configure a postgresql server with 
Hostname: 127.0.0.1
Port: 9032
Username and password as written up, i have

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 9032?
```

If i change the IP in docker-compose for 192.168.99.100, i manage to connect,
but the database is not initialized although there are sql files in the folder

```
\init\db\docker-entrypoint-initdb.d :
01_create_schema.sql
02_create_tables.sql
21_insert__data_demo.sql
```

So is it my connexion that is wrongly setup ? 
Or should i do it with 192.168.99.100, and it's the initialisation setup that is wrong in the docker-compose ?

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i solve the problem, but unfortunately without Docker Toolbox.
I bought a key for windows 10 pro (6€), upgraded the system really fast, and installed Docker Desktop.
Everything worked instantly.
Before the connexion ip was indeed 192.168.99.100, but i don't know why the sql scripts where not copied in the virtual environment, and the folder

```
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

remained empty.
So my solution was to upgrade the system, and everything is fine !